# setting up jenkins with jenkins.war

Tags: jenkins

I have installed latest jenkins.war from 
https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/

after that I have triggered that WAR file as
java -jar jenkins.war in command prompt.

I have attached the screen shots of the same.

As I could understand from the logs that, port which jenkins trying to operate on is already in use.

would appreciate the any help on this!

[image: Command Prompt after war execution]
[image: command prompt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Jenkins will bind on port 8080 (listening address will be http://localhost:8080), you can change this port by editing the `jenkins.xml` file that is located in the directory where you installed Jenkins.

Change it for another value and relaunch. (or try to find who is already listening on this 8080 port, probably a web server)

By the way, instead of downloading the jenkins.war, it would be better to use the [native windows installer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+Windows+Installer), that will install/start jenkins as a service.

Comment: able to install jenkins with native windows installer.  initially my antivirus was blocking it but managed to resolve it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port without editing `jenkins.xml`. This can be useful when you are doing an initial setup where you don't have a `jenkins.xml` yet.

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=<your port>
```

You can also run Jenkins this way with an existing `jenkins.xml`. In my case I can access the Jenkins UI using both ports. When one of both ports is already used by the system like in your case, Jenkins won't start.